# Making div scrollable without setting height

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to make div scrollable, without hard-coding its height? Usually when you want to make div scrollable, you need to set max-height, otherwise it will be expanding.

```
#element {
    overflow:auto;
    max-height: 100px;
}
```

In my case, I want height to be restricted by parents height (and parent is resizable), not by setting it in CSS.

Here is JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/mbrnwsk/58qSc/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for the `#content` to stretch to fill the remaining space in the parent minus the height of the `#title` element, you can do it with either CSS or JS. The CSS solution is simple, but you will have to adjust the offset of the `top` to ensure that it fits properly. By setting the other three offsets (left, bottom and right) to zero, we thereby force the `#content` element to stretch out completely.

```
#parent {
    border: 3px solid;
    height: 150px;
    position: relative;
}
#content {
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    background: cyan;
    top: 16px; /* This is based on the assumption that #title has a height of 16px */
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/58qSc/3/

---

For a more responsive solution, you will need to rely on JS to fetch the height of `#title`, and then set the `top` property of `#content` accordingly — the advantage of this is that it will respond well when the viewport size changes, also when the height of `#title` changes.

For the CSS, it's the same as above but we remove the `top` declaration. Instead, we delegate this to JS instead:

```
$(function() {
    $("#parent").resizable();

    // Function to set height
    var setContentHeight = function() {
        $('#content').css('top', $('#title').outerHeight());
    }

    // Recalculate when viewport changes
    // You can also bind this function to events that manipulate the dimension of #title
    $(window).resize(setContentHeight);

    // Run once when DOM is ready
    setContentHeight();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/58qSc/4/

The advantage of the JS-based solution is that:

- It is responsive — you can always recalculate `top` by binding the `setContentHeight()` function to any events that you can foresee will change the dimensions of `#title`.
- You don't have to manually update the `top` value when you alter the paddings, margins, heights (min-, max- or height), line-height of `#title`, or any of its children (if they exist)

Comment: Thank you, CSS solution suits my needs.

Answer (score 2):

```
height:100%;
```

will set it equal to the parents height.

See it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/58qSc/5/)

EDIT: The comment is right:  Need to add padding to the parent

```
#parent {padding-bottom: 1em;}
```

Comment: Not really, the div above (with id 'title') makes it not fitting inside the parent.